# Drop-UI for Braintree to search for customer id transaction and remove token or subscription

Tags: java, php, python, paypal

I want to allow customers to cancel their paypal/cc accounts quickly online.

Customers send us either: (Paypal email id) or (credit card: first 5 digits, last 4 digits, credit card type)

This is the process I'm looking to automate:

> ```
> 1.) We receive customer cancel request for paypal or credit card account
>
> 2.) Cancel request contains credit card or paypal account information:
> Paypal ID: Paypal email id  
> credit card Info: first 5 digits, last 4 digits, credit card type 
>
> 3.) We search Transactions to retrieve their customer ID and cancel subscriptions:
> a.) Search using all payment methods
> b.) Search using the entire Year 01/01/2018-12/30/2018
> c.) Enter Paypal ID or Credit Card Info
> d.) Retrieve Charge/Payment Token ID
> e.) Open Charge/Payment Token ID to find Customer ID
> f.) Open customer id and cancel subscriptions
> ```

```
`//CreditPaypal
TransactionSearchRequest request = new TransactionSearchRequest()
.creditCardNumber().startsWith("51051");
.creditCardNumber().endsWith("5100");
.creditCardCardType().in(CreditCard.CardType.VISA,         CreditCard.CardType.MASTER_CARD, CreditCard.CardType.DISCOVER, CreditCard.CardType.MAESTRO, CreditCard.CardType.JCB, CreditCard.CardType.UNIONPAY);
.createdAt().lessThanOrEqual(Calendar.getInstance());

Customer request = gateway.customer().find("the_customer_id");
customer.getPaymentMethods(); // array of PaymentMethod instances
request.getToken()

//Paypal
TransactionSearchRequest request2 = new TransactionSearchRequest()
.paypalAccountEmail().is("test@gmail.com");

Customer request2 = gateway.customer().find("the_customer_id");
customer.getPaymentMethods(); // array of PaymentMethod instances
request.getToken()`
```

I expect the output to be the payment method or payment token was cancelled or removed by using the customer ID or payment token.

Comment: Removed `perl` tag since there is not Perl at all here